# Can AppBarLayout with RecyclerView works without letting RecyclerView over-scroll?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a layout with CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout and RecyclerView as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#aaa"
    tools:context="com.elyeproj.recycleranimation.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/cheese_2"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#aaa"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It works fine where the AppBarLayout could shrink as the RecyclerView scroll as shown in GIF below. It won't scroll beyond row 100.

[image]

When the list is short, it is not scrollable, since the RecyclerView is wrap-content, as shown below

[image]

However, when the list is not too short, but not longer than the page height, the scrolling went beyond the row "100", and display some empty space as below.

[image]

My question is, for scenario 3, is it possible to have a way to prevent over-scroll, i.e. the scrowing happens until row 100 only, and the AppBarLayout still visible partly as above?

Answer (score 2):

Try RecyclerView height to match_parent.